# RFID reader and bluetooth connectivity

Tags: bluetooth, rfid, bluetooth-low-energy, nfc

Can an RFID reader detect bluetooth device?
I downloaded an application called RFID explorer on my phone. The application helps to get read by RFID readers. I switched on the bluetooth on my phone and showed it near an RFID reader. It doesn't work :(

I don't know whether this is a stupid experiment, but still would like to know if an RFID reader works with bluetooth enabled device.

Answer (score 1):

RFID has absolutely nothing to do with Bluetooth !

RFID is usually based on a technology called NFC (Near field communication).
It is intended for smartcards and ID badges etc. You need to switch on NFC on your phone and then hold the back of the phone near the RFID. You need the distance to be less than a couple of centimeters.

If your phone is an iPhone 6 then you might be out of luck because since this phone has NFC but you can only use it for payments. With an Android phone there are no limitations :-)

Comment: `RFID is usually based on a technology called NFC` I'd argue it's the other way around. Quote from Wikipedia: `NFC standards cover communications protocols and data exchange formats and are based on existing radio-frequency identification (RFID) standards [...]`

Comment: RFID is Radio Frequency Identification, and Near Field Communication (NFC) works on that protocol. Wherein NFC is a subset of RFID. I asked such a question because bluetooth as well as RFID is based on Radio Frequency communication, which was vague enough. I got confused though, thanx anyways :)